# Parse data from buffer of a bin file c

Tags: c, file, parsing, binaryfiles

I have a bin file wich contais some data, i am suposed to read that data and store it in variables. The problem is i dont know how to parse the data from the buffer.

```
FILE *file;
char *buffer;

//Abre o ficheiro
file = fopen("retail.bin", "rb");
if (!file)
{
    printf("Erro ao abrir %s\n", "retail.bin");
    return;
}

//Lê o conteúdo do ficheiro
while(fread(&buffer, sizeof(int), 1, file) == 1){
    printf("%d", buffer);
}

fclose(file);
```

Output: 53324477812552451219223312232012122211305213462334644247717440148531711811913243
34437515052573583

What i want is to be able to access every number separately. I tried: `printf("%s", buffer[0]);`

But the program stops working.

Comment: You need to know how the data were written to the buffer. Otherwise there is no way to tell how to read those data.

Comment: OT: As from the OP's sources the program runs into undefined behaviour as it misses to allocate memory to what `buffer` is pointing to, prior to reading data to it.

Comment: `char *buffer;` ----> `int buffer`

Comment: `printf("%d\n", buffer);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. The first is that you pass a pointer to a pointer to `fread`. The other is that you read an integer into a `char` buffer, i.e. a string. The third is that `buffer` is not allocated and points to a random location in memory. The fourth is that you print a "string" as an integer.

If you want to read an integer, then read it into an integer:

```
int value;
fread(&value, sizeof(value), 1, file);
printf("%d", value);
```